# Taking a root higher than 2

Tags: c++, square-root, cmath

I'm trying to take the 11th root of an expression and I'm getting a return of `-inf`.

```
std::cout << pow(j,(1.0/11.0)) << std::endl;
```

where `j` is just some `log` expression. I've checked that number to make sure it's valid, and it is. I'm thinking it's the way that the power expression is being run. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

And yes, I've included `cmath` into my work.

Comment: Full compile-able source code can help. Also input values used? ps: http://ideone.com

Comment: you can also use exp() : double _11th_root = exp(log(j)/11.0);

Comment: Be aware that taking roots lowers your precision in the same way that catastrophic cancellation can, for example, after a square root you halve your precision, I don't know how much precision an eleventh root would leave you but it won't be much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a valid reason for pow to return -inf, if your inputs are marginally sane. However in case you're passing in a negative number, something that may be worth trying is:

```
if(j==0) return 0;
if(j<0) return -pow(-j, 1.0/11.0);
return pow(j,1.0/11.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. try to look for FPU errors

   - the most common is forgotten return of float/double in some function
   - which leads to problems on FPU stack which is really small.
2. also you can try add this before pow

   ```
   asm { fninit; };
   ```

   - this resets the FPU so if you have problems on stack it will help
   - but of course do not do this in middle of some FPU computation
   - it would destroy its result
   - if you are not on x87 platform than this will not help
3. the value of j before crash will be a good start to share with us.
4. try to store the result of pow to some float/double variable

   - cout that variable not temporary heap memory location
   - if it prints -inf look also inside that variable if it is also -inf
   - (could be something wrong with the cout not pow ... )
5. minimize your code (turn off everything part by part)

   - and see if the problems is suddenly not there
   - hidden memory leaks and code overwrites are evil ...

Let us know what you have found.